# Java rarrange enum array

Tags: java

i was wondering how can i reorder enum so that all goats are at the beginning and all  sheep are at the end of the array. Right now it actually does the trick but until the array size > 100.. The reordering speed also matters so api methods are bit too slow. Any suggestions?

```
public class Sheep {


   enum Animal {sheep, goat};

   public static void main (String[] param) {

    reorder(Animal.values());
   }

   public static void reorder (Animal[] animals) {


       int l, r, i, j;

       i = l = 0; //left most element
       r = animals.length - 1;//right most element
       int mid = (r+l)/2; // middle element of the array
        for(i=0; i < animals.length;i++)
        {
            if(i < mid)
            {
                animals[i] = animals[l+1];

                System.out.println(animals[r]);

            } else if(i >= mid )
            {   
                animals[i] = animals[r-1];
                System.out.println(animals[r]);

            }

        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Since these are just simple `enum`s, couldn't you just count the number of goats, and then build an array with `N` goats followed by `length-N` sheep?  Using a sort algorithm doesn't make much sense when the domain only has two possibilities.  I'm not sure what your algorithm is doing, but it seems more complex than required.

Comment: Note: `Enum#values()` is a O(n) operation because it clones the array of values *every time* it is called. This is to avoid exactly what you are doing here. So if you do rearrange the array, keep a hold of the reference - the original values will be unchanged.

Comment: @Obicere - `values()` is only being called once in this program. There's no need to keep a reference.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, but also with this exact program the result of reorder (except the debugging prints) is ignored since he doesn't keep a reference to the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an `enum` implements `Comparable`, you can simply sort and then reverse the array:

```
public static void reorder(Animal[] animals) {
    Arrays.sort(animals);
    for (int i = 0, j = animals.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        Animal tmp = animals[i];
        animals[i] = animals[j];
        animals[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

You might also be able to do it with:

```
List<Animal> list = Arrays.asList(animals);
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

This basically does the same thing with API calls with the (very slight) overhead of wrapping the array in a `List` object. You can even do this:

```
Arrays.sort(animals, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

(Thanks to Bhesh Gurung for the idea.)

EDIT: If you have to deal with exactly two values, you can do much better by simply scanning from both ends, swapping as you find two elements out of order:

```
public static void reorder(Animal[] animals) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = animals.length - 1;
    while (first < last) {
        /*
         * The unsorted elements are in positions first..last (inclusive).
         * Everything before first is the higher animal; everything after
         * last is the lower animal.
         */
        while (animals[first].ordinal() == 1 && first < last) {
            ++first;
        }
        while (animals[last].ordinal() == 0 && first < last) {
            --last;
        }
        if (first < last) {
            /*
             * At this point, the sort conditions still hold and also we know
             * that the animals at first and last are both out of order
             */
            Animal temp = animals[first];
            animals[first] = animals[last];
            animals[last] = temp;
            ++first;
            --last;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if all you need to do is generate the right output (and not actually sort the array), then the approach suggested by @ajb in a comment is the best: just count how many sheep and goats there are and print the corresponding values that many times.

Comment: Posted just before me ;).

Comment: Sry, but where did you declare the int last? or whats the value of it?

Comment: I wonder if this would perform better than just doing `Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());`.

Comment: @user3024888 - Sorry. That was a typo (now fixed). It was supposed to be `j`.

Comment: hehe yeah i figured it out, funny is that it still didnt go through the junit test, its a bit too slow it took 3,079s but must be < 2,500. But still thank you!

Comment: @BheshGurung - `Collections` doesn't have a no-argument `reverseOrder()` method that returns a `Comparator`.

Comment: @user3024888 - Do you need to handle more than two `enum` values? If not, there's a much faster way of solving the problem.

Comment: @TedHopp: It's there http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29

Comment: @BheshGurung - Wow. Don't know how I missed that. It's certainly worth a try, but if OP only has to deal with two values, there's a better way.

Comment: Not able to picture it. Probably, by creating a new array?

Comment: @BheshGurung - I posted the code for the method I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have maximum performance for such a special case you may simply count the number of one of the two possible values and overwrite the array accordingly to get the result that sorting would create:

```
public static void reorder (Animal[] animals) {
    assert Animal.values().length==2;
    int numGoat=0;
    for(Animal a:animals) if(a==Animal.goat) numGoat++;
    Arrays.fill(animals, 0, numGoat, Animal.goat);
    Arrays.fill(animals, numGoat, animals.length, Animal.sheep);
```

}

You can see it as a modified version of [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).